Splitting of primes in abelian extensions
Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ an abelian number field. Using the Kronecker-Weber theorem, it is quite easy to show the following statement:
There is a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and a finite set $M\subseteq \{0,1,...,m-1\}$ such that for every rational prime $p$,
$$p \ \text{ splits completely in } \ K\phantom{aa}\Longleftrightarrow\phantom{aa}p \equiv k \bmod m \ \text{ for some }k\in M\text{.}$$
My question: In the general case, how explicitly can we describe the set $M$?
The problem for me is that the only proof of the statement I know about does not give any kind of description of the set $M$. It goes something like this:
Choose the number $m$ so that $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ ($=$ the $m$th cyclotomic field; use Kronecker-Weber). Choose the set $M$ as follows: Let $p_1,p_2,...$ be a list of all rational primes which split completely in $K$. Then, take for $M$ a complete set of representatives of the cosets $\{p_1+m\mathbb{Z}, \ p_2+m\mathbb{Z},...\}$ such that $M \subseteq \{0,1,...,m-1\}$. It then quite easy to show that the above equivalence holds.
The proof above does not tell us anything about how the set $M$ actually looks like. Can we make it more precise? Or maybe there is even algorithm which can compute $M$, given the number field $K$?
The only thing I know is that you can always compute $M$ if $K$ happens to be quadratic (using quadratic reciprocity of course). But what about the general case?

The abelian extension $K$ gives you a subgroup $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)/K)\subset \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)/\mathbb Q)=(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$. This is precisely the subset you are looking for.

Thanks for the answer! I am just trying to proof this but I have problems in the following case: $p$ is a prime which splits completely in $K$ but is ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. Is there an elementary way to treat this situation?

Edit: Found an answer to my question from the comment above (analyzing the proof of Kronecker-Weber shows that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ can be chosen in way s.t. the primes that ramify in $K$ are the same as the primes that ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$). Many thanks again!
